# d3.js Unexpected Behavior creating and entering Elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a very basic graph here. What I want to achieve is a little bit like this: [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Michelsonmorley-boxplot.svg/2000px-Michelsonmorley-boxplot.svg.png]

Every "Sub-Graph" contains of 4 data points.

The desired Structure is:

```
 .chart
  .chart__graph
    .chart__graph__exp1
    .chart__graph__exp2
    .chart__graph__opt
    .chart__graph__min
  .chart__graph
    .chart__graph__exp1
    .chart__graph__exp2
    .chart__graph__opt
    .chart__graph__min
  .chart__graph
    ....
```

This is my approach:

```
    var data = [
        {
            minimum: 4,
            optimum: 7,
            company: 6,
            competitor: 6
        },
        {
            minimum: 2,
            optimum: 4,
            company: 4,
            competitor:3
        },
        {
            minimum: 3,
            optimum: 7,
            company: 6,
            competitor: 3
        }
    ]

    d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__min").html(function(d) { return d.minimum; });
    d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__exp1").html(function(d) { return d.company; })
    d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__exp2").html(function(d) { return d.competitor; })
    d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__opt").html(function(d) { return d.optimum; })
```

According to the documentation/tutorials I expect it to create a subdiv, but it seems to ignore .selectAll(".chart__graph") completely. 
If I `.append()` the div manually, then It creates the subdiv for every run-through which is not desired. 
What am I missing to achieve my desired div-structure?
Also, what does `selectAll()` actually do?

Please don't mind the repetitive code, trying to wrap my head around the D3.js syntax for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the `div` with class `chart__graph` in enter, then create the child divs.

```
var chart_graph_ent = d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph")
chart_graph_ent.append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__min")
...
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph")//this is a wrong selection
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__opt")
```

It should have been

```
d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph__opt")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__opt")
```

What does this do:

1)    `d3.select(".chart") //this will select the DOM with class chart`

2)    `d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph__opt")`

This will return a selection of elements with class `chart__graph__opt` within the selection with class `".chart"`. Initially this will be empty selection.

3)

```
//to this selection set the data and call enter
    d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph__opt")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
```

4)

```
d3.select(".chart").selectAll(".chart__graph__opt")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div").attr("class", "chart__graph__opt")
```

to each data in the data set new div will be appended with class "chart__graph__opt"(same as the selection).

Hope this clears some concerns.

Comment: Thanks, that is the easiest to follow. Unfortunately the child-divs (".chart__graph__opt") are now not displayed into its parent container (".chart__graph), but right next to each other. Could you tweak your example maybe?

Answer (score -1):

"selectAll" selects nodes by tag name ".chart_graph" and d3 attempts to append the new nodes in the ".chart" object.